# Unable to find the source package for libreoffice

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice

I am trying to build `libreoffice` from source but when I try to run

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libreoffice
```

I get the following error `Unable to find the source package for libreoffice`. I tried to find a solution to the same. I found the following on [this](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Linux_Build_Dependencies) page

> Some mirrors do not copy the sources. In that case you will need to switch to a mirror that does. This would cause the "Unable to find the source package for libreoffice" error in the next step.

Could anyone help me with the process of switiching to mirror, if that is necessary? Or is there another way to tackle the same?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting their [official documentation](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Linux_Build_Dependencies):

> To run build-dep, your repository list should include the source-code repository. Make sure you have a deb-src line in /etc/apt/sources.list for the main repository.

I suggest you make sure that the following line is present in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

`deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main`

Make sure to read the linked documentation page thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

enable the universe repository 'sudo add-apt-repository universe' this needs to be done starting with Ubuntu 18

Ok if you have it already enabled than:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Comment: Does not solve the problem. I got `'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.` Still gettting the same error on building dependencies for libreoffice.

Comment: OP did not ask for steps to install libreoffice, instead they wanted to set up the build environment for libreoffice. This answer speaks about the former, hence, not relevant.